# How to use filters in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

i am trying to filter dataframe with pandas. I tried many different syntax, but it was not possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

domains_pzn = pd.read_pickle("domains_pzn")
filter1 = domains_pzn["t_val_active"]==1

domains_pzn.where(filter1, inplace  = True)
domains_pzn
```

What I am trying: I have a column "t_val_active" in my dataframe. I want to filter the datasets to the value with 1 in this column.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `domains_pzn[filter1]` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The filtering still does not work, I can see all values.

Comment: that's because filtering the dataframe does not overwrite it. If you want to do that you need to do `domains_pzn = domains_pzn[filter1]`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

domains_pzn = pd.read_pickle("domains_pzn")
domains_pzn[domains_pzn["t_val_active"]==1]

#domains_pzn.where(filter1, inplace  = True)
#domains_pzn
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try this, i got an error message: "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object"

Comment: share sample data